# Unity C#, 2D game Spawning loot at selected location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, instantiation

Im currently making 2D game space shooter like game in unity.
My issue is with the Loot spawning script. If enemies spawn at fast rate then loot will spawn not at the destroyed enemy but one of the ones that just spawned.

The 2 Scripts that are used for all my detection and loot spawning:

```
public void onDeath(bool isDead)
{
    if (isDead == true)
    {
        if (Random.value <= dropProbability)
        {
            Instantiate(Loot.transform, Loot.transform.position = Enemy.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

This script takes in 2 game objects first is for my loot and second the enemy.
I instantiate my loot on position of my enemy.

```
void Update()
{
    if (healthPoints <= 0)
    {
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            FindObjectOfType<LootSpawn>().onDeath(true);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }      
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ammo") != true)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag != this.gameObject.tag)
        {
            healthPoints--;
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player1") == true)
            {
                FindObjectOfType<uiElements>().RemoveHealth();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the global script that I use for "ALL" detection this includes bullets, player and enemy.
The script works fine when spawn interval between each enemy is higher than 2.5seconds
anything less causes this issue I'll attach 2 screenshot to visually show my issue
[Before The Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlFbm.jpg),
[After Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El8No.jpg)

Finally to clarify I want my "Loot" to always spawn at the "Destroyed" Enemy regardless of how many enemies are on field or how fast they are instantiated onto the field.
Without making my code much longer and making it messy
can anyone point me in right direction? would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Whats wrong with passing the position to spawn the loot at to the `onDeath` method? The you could call `onDeath(true, transform.position)`.

Comment: `Instantiate(Loot.transform, Loot.transform.position = Enemy.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0));` Where does `Enemey` get defined? Also, `onDeath(bool isDead)` You would think that if you're calling a function called *onDead* that the enemy would always be dead when this call is made, yet you pass a boolean saying whether or not the enemy *is actually dead.*

Comment: my bad for some reason it cut my code when I copy and pasted 
    `public GameObject Loot;
    public GameObject Enemy;
    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float dropProbability = 1f;
     public bool isDead = false;` Enemy is just a gameobject. so onDead is only triggered when healthPoints reaches 0. As for the call its because each time it gets called the enemy dies so it just triggers the response

Comment: I think your main issue is coming from FindObjectOfType<LootSpawn> and possibly your enemy object (or start method). FindObjectOfType is a very slow function that searches the entire scene for the first instance, any instance, of the LootSpawn object. It's possible you may be creating one accidentally and accessing by using this script instead of the one specific to the now dead enemy. Enemy is another issue, mostly because I don't know where it's value came from in the onDeath function. Some more info on this would help me track the issue a little better.

Comment: At a glance it looks like the scripts are meant to run asynchronously or possible at different fixed intervals. You may want to consider using Coroutines as well and just feeding all the information you need (loot spawn position, loot prefab) in as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin Danger Johnson what you said is correct, this is one year old question though.
I believe what you said was actually the solution. I have long since solved this issue (and looking now I find it weird how I struggled with it hehe, but progress makes us better I guess).

For anyone would ever have similar issue.
Dont use FindObjectOfType 
Use unity's 
GetComponent instead:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html